# Is this the 'right' proof that tensor products of vector spaces commute up to isomorphism?

Tags: tensor-products

Let $f: V \times W \to W \otimes V$ be given by $f(v,w) = \otimes(w,v)$. The function $f$ is bilinear since $f(v_1+v_1,w) = \otimes(v_1+v_2,w) = \otimes (v_1,w)+\otimes(v_2,w) = f(v_1,w)+f(v_2,w)$ by bilinearity of $\otimes$ (not going to do the scalars or second slot). Then the universal property says that $$
\exists! \text{ linear } T_*:V \otimes W \to W \otimes V:T_*(v \otimes w) = f(v,w) = w \otimes v.
$$
At this point the only way I know how to finish the proof is to say that there is a function $g:W \times V \to V \otimes W$ with $g(w,v) = \otimes(v,w)$, show that is also bilinear, then use the universal property again to get a function that looks like $T_*^{-1}$. I am wondering if that is the right way to finish off or whether I should just directly show $T_*$ is bijective. I am not sure about this bit, but I think I can say $T_*$ is onto since for any $w \otimes v \in W \otimes V$, $T_*(v \otimes w) = w \otimes v$. Injective I am also stuck on.

Comment: Your $T_*$ is indeed injective.

Comment: Why is that? If you have $T_*(v \otimes w) = T_*(a \otimes b)$ then you get $w \otimes v = b \otimes a$. That doesn't give $a \otimes b = v \otimes w$, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your idea of building an inverse map, and showing it is an inverse map, is the right way since (i) it gives you experience building maps out of tensor products with the universal property (which is the best way to get used to building maps out of tensor products) and (ii) it carries over with no changes to prove there is an isomorphism $M \otimes_R N \to N \otimes_R M$ for tensor products of *modules* $M$ and $N$ over a commutative ring $R$. Proofs in the vector space case that rely on bases of vector spaces will not work in the module setting since modules need not have bases.

Answer (score 0):

One direct way to do so is following. Recall that to each elementary tensor $v\otimes w$ in $V\otimes W$, one can associate a functional $v\otimes w:BL(V\times W)\to \mathbb C$, defined as $(v\otimes w)(B)=B(v,w)$. Where $BL(V\times W)$ is the space of all bilinear forms on $V\times W$. Thus we can identify $V\otimes W$ with the subspace of $BL(V\times W)^\#$ (algebraic dual) spanned by elementary tensors. Now suppose $T_*(z)=0$ for some $z\in V\otimes W$. Write $z=\sum_{i=1}^nv_i\otimes w_i$ where $\{v_i\}$ is a subset of the Hamel basis for $V$. For any  $f\in V^\#$ and $g\in W^\#$, we can define a bilinear form $B:W\times V\to \mathbb C$ as $B(w\otimes v)=g(w)f(v)$ extended linearly to all tensors.  Thus

$(\sum_{i=1}^nw_i\otimes v_i)(B)=\sum_{i=1}^ng(w_i)f(v_i)$=0 holds for all $f\in V^\#$  and $g\in W^\#$. Fix $g\in W^\#$, then

$f(\sum_{i=1}^ng(w_i)v_i)=0$ for all $f\in V^\#$. Thus,

$\sum_{i=1}^ng(w_i)v_i=0$ (because algebraic dual separates points).

But $\{v_i\}_{i=1}^n$ is a linearly independent set and hence,

$g(w_i)=0$ for each $i=1,2,..,n$. Since, $g$ was arbitrarily fixed, we can conclude that $w_i=0$ for each $i=1,2,..,n$. Thus, $\sum_{i=1}^nv_i\otimes w_i=0$ and concluding that $T_*$ is injective.